# Using compound literals in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, static, initializer-list

I would like to initialize a variable of type `Matrix4` with a [`compound literal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal). My constructor expects a `float*`.

So here is my line of initialization:

```
const Matrix4 Matrix4::identity ( (float[16]) { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } );
```

This seems like it should work, but Visual Studio says it's "non standard explicit type conversion". But I would like to keep the "one-line initialization", except if there really is a more convenient way.

Comment: You need to show more code, like how `Matrix4` is defined. Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Whatever the content of the constructor, the problem is VS not recognizing it + the fact that it doesn't look like the cleanest way to do it, is it?

Comment: C++ does not have compound literals. That is a C feature

Comment: You could change your function to accept `array<float, 16> const&`

Answer (score 4):

You have overcomplicated the question with irrelevant static member detail. In fact, the question can be easily reproduced as:

```
void foo(float* );

void k() {
    foo((float[4]){1, 2, 3, 4});
}
```

What you have here is a 'compound literal', defined for C99. It is not available in C++ by standard, but some compilers have extensions which support this. From the question itself, it seems like MSVC also supports this extension - it mentions this in the message - but doesn't allow the code. Probably there is a way to explicitly enable it on MSVC, but I am not expert on this.

I do not really see a reason to write non-conformant code in this case, so I would advocate against it.

Answering the question after edit, there are really several ways how one can achieve a single-line call. One could make function to accept `std::initializer_list<float>` for variable number of arguments, `std::array<float, 16>` for fixed number of arguments, or `gsl::span`.